# Query in MongoDB does not return result

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a recipe database which I have created for my new business but unfortunately this query keeps on coming up with syntax errors.

I have validated the query through checkers online but to no avail.

```
    db.recipes.find( {
        $and: [
            { $or: [ { "calories": { $lt : 500 } }, { "calories" : { $gt: 300 } } ] },
            { $or: [ { "ingredients": "lean chicken mince" }, { "fat" : { $lt : 50 } } ] }
    ]
    }
    )
```

The query above is supposed to return the first recipe which is below.

This is the code for the recipe database

```
{
        "Recipe_name": " Caribbean Chicken Patty ",
        "Recipe_desc": "You'll never want a burger again.",
        "Recipe_serves": 4,
        "Recipe_totaltime": 30,
        "Recipe_nutrient": {
          "calories": 417,
          "fat": 30,
          "satfat": 28,
          "carbs": 32,
          "fiber": 5,
          "sugar": 2,
          "protein": 15
        },
        "method": [
            {
              "step": 1,
              "instruction": "Shape beef into 4 thin patties slightly larger than slices of bread. Heat large cast iron skillet on medium-high. Season patties with ½ teaspoon each salt and pepper and cook 2 minutes per side; transfer to a plate."
            },
            {
              "step": 2,
              "instruction": " Wipe out skillet and return to medium-low heat. Spread mayo on 1 side of each slice of bread. In 2 batches, place 2 slices bread mayo-side down in the skillet. Top each with 1½ slices Swiss cheese, a beef patty, caramelized onions, 1½ slices American cheese, and second slice of bread, mayo-side up. Place small skillet (wrapped in foil) on top of sandwiches to press and cook until bread is golden brown and crisp, 3 minutes per side."
            }
          ],
          "ingredients": [
            {
              "Name": " lean chicken mince",
              "Measurement": 500,
              "unit": "g"
            },
            {
              "Name": "salt and pepper",
              "Measurement": 5,
              "unit": "g"
            },
            {
              "Name": "mayonnaise",
              "Measurement": 20,
              "unit": "g"
            },
            {
              "Name": "rye bread",
              "Measurement": 8,
              "unit": "item"
            },
            {
              "Name": "thin slices Swiss cheese",
              "Measurement": 8,
              "unit": "item"
            },
            {
              "Name": "caramelized onions",
              "Measurement": 150,
              "unit": "g"
            },
    
            {
              "Name": "thin slices American cheese",
              "Measurement": 6,
              "unit": "item"
            }
          ],
        "tags": [
          "caribbean",
          "quick",
          "cheesy",
          "chicken",
          "starter"
        ],
        "difficulty": [
          "easy"
        ]
      },
    {
            "Recipe_name": "Cookie Dough Ice Cream Sandwiches",
            "Recipe_desc": "This decadent dessert will literally ruin you for all other ice cream sandwiches.",
            "Recipe_serves": 12,
            "Recipe_totaltime": 5,
            "Recipe_nutrient": {
                "calories": 250,
                "fat": 30,
                "satfat": 28,
                "carbs": 32,
                "fiber": 5,
                "sugar": 10,
                "protein": 20
            },
            "method": [
            {
                        "step": 1,
                        "instruction": "Line a large baking sheet with parchment paper, leaving overhang on sides. In a large bowl, stir together melted butter, both sugars, milk, and vanilla until combined. Stir in flour and salt, then fold in chocolate chips. "
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 2,
                        "instruction": "Press cookie dough into prepared baking sheet, evening it out as much as possible (a cutting board can help). Top with a second piece of parchment and freeze until firm, 1 hour."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 3,
                        "instruction": "Remove cookie dough from pan and place on a cutting board. Slice dough down the center. Scoop ice cream on one half, then gently place other half of cookie dough on top. Transfer back to pan and freeze at least 4 hours and up to overnight."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 4,
                        "instruction": "Slice into sandwiches and serve."
                    }
                ],
                "ingredients": [
            {
                        "Name": " butter sticks melted",
                        "Measurement": 2,
                        "unit": "item"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "brown sugar",
                        "Measurement": 500,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "sugar",
                        "Measurement": 350,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "milk",
                        "Measurement": 175,
                        "unit": "ml"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "vanilla",
                        "Measurement": 1,
                        "unit": "tbs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "flour",
                        "Measurement": 500,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "salt",
                        "Measurement": 1,
                        "unit": "tbs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "chocolate chips",
                        "Measurement": 200,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "vanila ice cream softened",
                        "Measurement": 400,
                        "unit": "g"
                    }
                ],
        "tags": [
                "cookie",
                "ice cream",
                "sweet",
                "dessert"
            ],
    
        "difficulty": [
                "easy"
        ]
    },
    
    {
            "Recipe_name": "Impossible quiche",
            "Recipe_desc": "A beautiful golden brown ham and cheese quiche that will delight the whole family.",
            "Recipe_serves": 4,
            "Recipe_totaltime": 50,
            "Recipe_nutrient": {
                "calories": 250,
                "fat": 30,
                "satfat": 28,
                "carbs": 32,
                "fiber": 5,
                "sugar": 10,
                "protein": 25
            },
            "method": [
            {
                        "step": 1,
                        "instruction": "Preheat oven to 200°C. Grease a 5 cup capacity pie dish."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 2,
                        "instruction": "Combine ham, onion, cheese, flour, salt and pepper in a medium bowl. Scatter over base of dish."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 3,
                        "instruction": "Whisk eggs and milk together in a large jug and pour over ham mixture. Cook for about 40 minutes or until puffed and golden. Cool slightly. Serve warm or cold."
                    }
                ],
                "ingredients": [
            {
                        "Name": "ham",
                        "Measurement": 120,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "onion",
                        "Measurement": 1,
                        "unit": "item"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "red onion",
                        "Measurement": 1,
                        "unit": "item"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "cheese",
                        "Measurement": 180,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "flour",
                        "Measurement": 50,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "eggs",
                        "Measurement": 4,
                        "unit": "item"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": " milk",
                        "Measurement": 100,
                        "unit": "ml"
                    }
                ],
            "tags": [
                "quick",
                "spanish",
                "main",
                "healthy"
            ],
            "difficulty": [
                "easy"
            ]
    },
    
    
    {
            "Recipe_name": "Pumpkin, broccoli and bacon pasta",
            "Recipe_desc": "This one-pot pasta wonder is ready in 30 minutes and the pasta cooks in the sauce!",
            "Recipe_serves": 4,
            "Recipe_totaltime": 30,
            "Recipe_nutrient": {
                "calories": 350,
                "fat": 10,
                "satfat": 28,
                "carbs": 32,
                "fiber": 5,
                "sugar": 5,
                "protein": 11
            },
            "method": [{
                        "step": 1,
                        "instruction": "Heat oil in a large heavy-based saucepan or flameproof casserole dish over medium-high heat. Add onion, bacon and pumpkin. Cook, stirring occasionally, for 5 minutes or until onion is softened. Add garlic and thyme. Stir to combine."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 2,
                        "instruction": "Add chicken stock and 2 cups cold water. Cover. Bring to the boil. Add spaghetti. Reduce heat to medium. Simmer, uncovered, for 10 minutes, stirring occasionally. Add broccoli. Simmer for 5 minutes, stirring occasionally, or until pasta and broccoli are tender and the sauce has thickened."
                    },
    
                    {
                        "step": 3,
                        "instruction": "Remove from heat. Remove and discard the thyme sprigs. Stir in cream. Season with salt and pepper. Serve pasta sprinkled with pine nuts, basil leaves and parmesan."
                    }
                ],
                "ingredients": [
            {
                        "Name": " extra virgin olive oil",
                        "Measurement": 1,
                        "unit": "tbs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "bacon",
                        "Measurement": 6,
                        "unit": "item"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "red onion",
                        "Measurement": 1,
                        "unit": "item"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "pumpkin",
                        "Measurement": 500,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "garlic cloves",
                        "Measurement": 2,
                        "unit": "item"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "fresh thyme",
                        "Measurement": 4,
                        "unit": "item"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "chicken stock",
                        "Measurement": 100,
                        "unit": "ml"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "spaghetti",
                        "Measurement": 200,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "cream",
                        "Measurement": 125,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "pinenuts",
                        "Measurement": 2,
                        "unit": "tbs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "black pepper",
                        "Measurement": 2,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "cheese",
                        "Measurement": 20,
                        "unit": "g"
                  }
        ],
            "tags": [
                "hearty",
                "quick",
                "main",
                "healthy"
            ],
            "difficulty": [
                "medium"
            ]
    },
    
    {
            "Recipe_name": "Cottage Pie",
            "Recipe_desc": "This great-value family favourite freezes beautifully and is a guaranteed crowd-pleaser",
            "Recipe_serves": 0,
            "Recipe_totaltime": 1,
            "Recipe_nutrient": {
                "calories": 1500,
                "fat": 30,
                "satfat": 28,
                "carbs": 32,
                "fiber": 5,
                "sugar": 10,
                "protein": 250
            },
            "method": [
            {
                        "step": 1,
                        "instruction": "Heat 1 tbsp olive oil in a large saucepan and fry 11⁄4 kg beef mince until browned – you may need to do this in batches. Set aside as it browns."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 2,
                        "instruction": "Put the other 2 tbsp olive oil into the pan, add 2 finely chopped onions, 3 chopped carrots and 3 chopped celery sticks and cook on a gentle heat until soft, about 20 mins."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 3,
                        "instruction": "Add 2 finely chopped garlic cloves, 3 tbsp plain flour and 1 tbsp tomato purée, increase the heat and cook for a few mins, then return the beef to the pan."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 4,
                        "instruction": "Pour over a large glass of red wine, if using, and boil to reduce it slightly before adding the 850 ml beef stock, 4 tbsp Worcestershire sauce, a few thyme sprigs and 2 bay leaves."
                    },
    
                    {
                        "step": 5,
                        "instruction": "Bring to a simmer and cook, uncovered, for 45 mins. By this time the gravy should be thick and coating the meat. Check after about 30 mins – if a lot of liquid remains, increase the heat slightly to reduce the gravy a little. Season well, then discard the bay leaves and thyme stalks."
                    },
    
                    {
                        "step": 6,
                        "instruction": "Meanwhile, make the mash. In a large saucepan, cover the 1.8kg potatoes which you've peeled and chopped, in salted cold water, bring to the boil and simmer until tender."
                    },
    
                    {
                        "step": 7,
                        "instruction": "Drain well, then allow to steam-dry for a few mins. Mash well with the 225 ml milk, 25g butter, and three-quarters of the 200g strong cheddar cheese, then season with freshly grated nutmeg and some salt and pepper."
                    },
    
                    {
                        "step": 8,
                        "instruction": "Spoon the meat into 2 ovenproof dishes. Pipe or spoon on the mash to cover. Sprinkle on the remaining cheese."
                    },
    
                    {
                        "step": 9,
                        "instruction": "f eating straight away, heat oven to 220C/200C fan/gas 7 and cook for 25-30 mins, or until the topping is golden. If you want to use a slow cooker, brown your mince in batches then tip into your slow cooker and stir in the vegetables, flour, purée, wine, stock, Worcestershire sauce and herbs with some seasoning. Cover and cook on High for 4-5 hours. Make the mash following the previous steps, and then oven cook in the same way to finish."
                    }
                ],
                "ingredient": [
            {
                        "Name": " olive oil",
                        "Measurement": 3,
                        "unit": "tbs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "mince",
                        "Measurement": 500,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "red onion",
                        "Measurement": 2,
                        "unit": "item"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "garlic clove",
                        "Measurement": 2,
                        "unit": "item"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "tomatoe puree",
                        "Measurement": 15,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "parsley",
                        "Measurement": 3,
                        "unit": "item"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "beef stock",
                        "Measurement": 850,
                        "unit": "ml"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "potatoes",
                        "Measurement": 1800,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "milk",
                        "Measurement": 200,
                        "unit": "ml"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "butter",
                        "Measurement": 25,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "cheese",
                        "Measurement": 200,
                        "unit": "g"
                    }
                ],
            "tags": [
                "english",
                "hearty",
                "main",
                "meaty"
            ],
            "difficulty": [
                "high"
            ]
    },
    
    {
            "Recipe_name": "Caramel apple puddings",
            "Recipe_desc": "Quintessentially British ingredients make up Frances Auger's comforting puds, impressing the judges of Britain's Best Pud",
            "Recipe_serves": 4,
            "Recipe_totaltime": 59,
            "Recipe_nutrient": {
                "calories": 400,
                "fat": 10,
                "satfat": 8,
                "carbs": 32,
                "fiber": 5,
                "sugar": 20,
                "protein": 17
            },
            "method": [
            {
                        "step": 1,
                        "instruction": "Heat oven to 180C/160C fan/gas 4. Lightly butter and flour 6 x 8cm deep ramekins, tapping out excess flour. Heat the butter in a pan until foaming, add the apple and cook for 1 min on a medium heat. Toss in the sugar and cook until dissolved. Divide between the ramekins."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 2,
                        "instruction": "For the puddings, beat the butter and sugar together with an electric whisk until fully combined. In a separate bowl, mix together the egg, buttermilk then stir this into the butter mixture. Fold in the flour, ground ginger, baking powder, bicarbonate of soda and a pinch of salt. Divide between the ramekins so they are filled to 1 cm below the top. Place them on a baking tray and bake for 20 mins, until golden and risen."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 3,
                        "instruction": "Serve warm, dusted with icing sugar. Accompany with cream or custard."
                    }
                ],
                "ingredients": [
            {
                        "Name": " butter",
                        "Measurement": 120,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "apple",
                        "Measurement": 1,
                        "unit": "item"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "brown sugar",
                        "Measurement": 200,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "egg",
                        "Measurement": 1,
                        "unit": "item"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "buttermilk",
                        "Measurement": 200,
                        "unit": "ml"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "flour",
                        "Measurement": 100,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "baking powder",
                        "Measurement": 1,
                        "unit": "tbs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "bicarbonate of soda",
                        "Measurement": 1,
                        "unit": "tbs"
                    }
                ],
            "tags": [
                "apple",
                "sweet",
                "dessert"
            ],
            "difficulty": [
                "medium"
            ]
    },
    
    {
        "Recipe_name": "Chorizo & mozzarella gnocchi bake",
        "Recipe_desc": "Upgrade cheesy tomato pasta with gnocchi, chorizo and mozzarella for a comforting bake that makes an excellent midweek meal",
        "Recipe_serves": 6,
        "Recipe_totaltime": 30,
        "Recipe_nutrient": {
          "calories": 390,
          "fat": 10,
          "satfat": 6,
          "carbs": 26,
          "fiber": 4,
          "sugar": 6,
          "protein": 35
        },
        "method": [
            {
              "step": 1,
              "instruction": "Heat the oil in a medium pan over a medium heat. Fry the onion and garlic for 8-10 mins until soft. Add the chorizo and fry for 5 mins more. Tip in the tomatoes and sugar, and season. Bring to a simmer, then add the gnocchi and cook for 8 mins, stirring often, until soft. Heat the grill to high."
            },
            {
              "step": 2,
              "instruction": "Stir ¾ of the mozzarella and most of the basil through the gnocchi. Divide the mixture between six ovenproof ramekins, or put in one baking dish. Top with the remaining mozzarella, then grill for 3 mins, or until the cheese is melted and golden. Season, scatter over the remaining basil and serve with green salad."
            },
          ],
        "ingredients": [
            {
              "Name": "Olive oil",
              "Measurement": 1,
              "unit": "tsp"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Onion, finely chopped",
              "Measurement": 1,
              "unit": "item"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Garlic crushed",
              "Measurement": 2,
              "unit": "item"
            },
            {
              "Name": "chorizo",
              "Measurement": 120,
              "unit": "g"
            },
            {
              "Name": "cans chopped tomatoes",
              "Measurement": 800,
              "unit": "g"
            },
            {
              "Name": "caster sugar",
              "Measurement": 1,
              "unit": "tbs"
            },
            {
              "Name": "fresh gnocchi",
              "Measurement": 600,
              "unit": "g"
            },
            {
              "Name": "mozzarella ball,",
              "Measurement": 125,
              "unit": "g"
            },
            {
              "Name": "basil",
              "Measurement": 5,
              "unit": "g"
            }
          ],
        "tags": [
          "cheese",
          "chorizo",
          "main",
          "healthy"
        ],
        "difficulty": [
          "easy"
        ]
      },
    
    
      {
        "Recipe_name": "Chicken & chorizo ragu",
        "Recipe_desc": "Serve this delicious chicken and chorizo ragu over rice or pasta as an easy midweek dinner for the family. You can freeze any leftovers for another day",
        "Recipe_serves": 4,
        "Recipe_totaltime": 1,
        "Recipe_nutrient": {
          "calories": 1500,
          "fat": 30,
          "satfat": 28,
          "carbs": 32,
          "fiber": 5,
          "sugar": 10,
          "protein": 250
        },
        "method": [
            {
              "step": 1,
              "instruction": "Fry the chorizo over a medium heat in a large saucepan or flameproof casserole dish for 5 mins or until it releases its oil and starts to char at the edges. Add the onion and fry for 5 mins more or until soft. Tip in the garlic and cook for 2 mins before stirring in the paprika and sundried tomatoes. Add the chicken thighs and fry for 2 mins each side until they are well coated in the spices and beginning to brown."
            },
            {
              "step": 2,
              "instruction": "Pour in the chopped tomatoes and stock, and turn the heat down. Cover and cook for 40 mins until the chicken is falling apart and the sauce is thick. Stir the lemon juice through. Serve by piling spoonfuls of the ragu into hot jacket potatoes with parsley sprinkled over and a dollop of soured cream, if you like."
            }
          ],
          "ingredients": [{
              "Name": " chorizo",
              "Measurement": 120,
              "unit": "g"
            },
            {
              "Name": "chicken",
              "Measurement": 400,
              "unit": "g"
            },
            {
              "Name": "red onion",
              "Measurement": 1,
              "unit": "item"
            },
            {
              "Name": "garlic clove",
              "Measurement": 2,
              "unit": "item"
            },
            {
              "Name": "sundried tomatoes",
              "Measurement": 200,
              "unit": "g"
            },
            {
              "Name": "parsley",
              "Measurement": 3,
              "unit": "item"
            },
            {
              "Name": "chicken stock",
              "Measurement": 100,
              "unit": "ml"
            },
            {
              "Name": "shallots",
              "Measurement": 200,
              "unit": "g"
            },
            {
              "Name": "lemon",
              "Measurement": 1,
              "unit": "item"
            },
            {
              "Name": "dry white wine",
              "Measurement": 2,
              "unit": "tbs"
            },
            {
              "Name": "black pepper",
              "Measurement": 10,
              "unit": "g"
            },
            {
              "Name": "jacket potatoes",
              "Measurement": 200,
              "unit": "g"
            }
          ],
        "tags": [
          "chicken",
          "spanish",
          "main",
          "healthy"
        ],
        "difficulty": [
          "hard"
        ]
    },
    {
            "Recipe_name": "Perfect Birthday Cake",
            "Recipe_desc": "This adult Funfetti cake is basically the birthday cake of our dreams. Three layers of tender vanilla cakes are covered with a not-too-sweet and slightly tangy buttercream.",
            "Recipe_serves": 16,
            "Recipe_totaltime": 2,
            "Recipe_nutrient": {
                "calories": 466,
                "fat": 20,
                "satfat": 8,
                "carbs": 32,
                "fiber": 5,
                "sugar": 10,
                "protein": 9.7
            },
            "method": [
                    {
                        "step": 1,
                        "instruction": "Make cake: Preheat oven to 350° and line three 8 inch cake pans with parchment paper."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 2,
                        "instruction": "In a large bowl using hand mixer (or in the bowl of a stand mixer), beat together butter and sugar until light and fluffy. Add eggs one at a time, beating well after each addition. Add vanilla and mix until combined."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 3,
                        "instruction": "In another large bowl, whisk together flour, cornstarch, baking powder, and salt. Add half of the dry ingredients to the wet ingredients, beating until just combined. Pour in the milk and mix until fully incorporated. Add remaining dry ingredients and stir until just combined. Fold in sprinkle"
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 4,
                        "instruction": "Divide batter evenly between prepared cake pans. Bake until slightly golden on top and a toothpick inserted into the middle comes out clean, about 30 to 35 minutes. Let cool completely."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": 5,
                        "instruction": "Meanwhile, make buttercream: in a large bowl using a hand mixer, beat butter until light and fluffy, 2 to 3 minutes. Add powdered sugar, sour cream, vanilla, heavy cream, and salt and beat until smooth."
                    },
                ],
                "ingredients": [
                    {
                        "Name": " butter sticks, softened",
                        "Measurement": 3,
                        "unit": "items"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": " granulated sugar",
                        "Measurement": 550,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "large eggs",
                        "Measurement": 4,
                        "unit": "item"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": " pure vanilla extract",
                        "Measurement": 1,
                        "unit": "tbs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "all-purpose flour",
                        "Measurement": 650,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "cornstarch",
                        "Measurement": 3,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "baking powder",
                        "Measurement": 2,
                        "unit": "tbs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "salt",
                        "Measurement": 2,
                        "unit": "tbs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": " milk",
                        "Measurement": 175,
                        "unit": "ml"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "sprinkles",
                        "Measurement": 50,
                        "unit": "g"
                    }
                ],
            "tags": [
                "cakes",
                "birthday",
                "dessery",
                "sweet"
            ],
            "difficulty": [
                "medium"
            ]
      }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the document , your correct query is the following:

```
 db.recipes.find( 
{ $and: [ 
    { $or: [ 
        { "Recipe_nutrient.calories": { $lt : 500 } },
        { "Recipe_nutrient.calories" : { $gt: 300 } } 
      ] },
    { $or: [ 
        { "ingredients.Name": " lean chicken mince" },
        { "Recipe_nutrient.fat" : { $lt : 50 } } 
      ] }    
       ] 
 } )
```